# Adding text above vertical and horizontal column lines

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I currently made the following table;
[image]

Which corresponds to this code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
&                                    &             \\
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Small Value}   & Big Value   \\ \cline{2-3} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Small Neutral} & Big Neutral \\ \cline{2-3} 
& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Small Growth}  & Big Growth 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would like to add some text above the vertical separation line, as well as to the left of the horizontal lines. Specifically, I would like something as follows:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: The text above the vertical line is quite easy if you replace your first empty line with `& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Median ME}                    \\ `.

Comment: Thank you that works. Would it perhaps be possible to do something similar with  multirow for the text for the midrules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` as well as some simplification fo your code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ll|l}
                                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Median ME}       \\
\multirow{2.2}{*}{70\textsuperscript{th} BE/ME percentile}& Small Value   & Big Value           \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multirow{2.2}{*}{30\textsuperscript{th} BE/ME percentile}& Small Neutral & Big Neutral         \\ \cline{2-3} 
                                                          & Small Growth  & Big Growth 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```